# Repeated Quine program

Tags: computability, recreational

A [Quine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29) is a computer program which produces a copy of its own source code as its only output. Is there any Quine program that could print itself out n times, with n specified some way in the program?

Comment: Could you please provide more information about what is a Quine program? (Also please read the [FAQ](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq) and [how to ask a good question](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/300/how-to-ask-a-good-question) if you have not read yet.)

Comment: @Kaveh: I re-added the logic tag. Quines originate in logic and the study of self-reference, self-application, etc, so it seem apropos.

Comment: A great resource on quines: http://www.nyx.net/~gthompso/quine.htm

Comment: Sorry, it is the first time I hear the phrase, I was used to self-copying/self-replicating/self-producing program and have not seen it being called a Quine program! Would like to know who has coined this name, wiki does not seem to give any clue. Anyway, I think recursion theory tag would be more appropriate than general logic tag.

Comment: Btw, I don't think there is any need to write the code of such a program, the existence follows easily from [Kleene's fixed point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_recursion_theorem).

Comment: @Kaveh: Willard V. O. Quine was a philosopher and logician who studied self-reference. See the great book _"Godel, Escher, Bach - An Eternal Golden Braid"_ by Douglas Hofstadter.

Comment: @Walter Bishop: Thank you, I already know who Quine is and am familiar with his work to some extent. Pardon me, but are you saying the name "Quine program" is coined by *the great* book GEB? (My search on Google scholar for "Quine Program" -philosophy returns only 4 articles, one from 2007 and the rest from 2009/2010.)

Comment: @Kaveh: Yes I suspect that the term _"Quine program"_ has been coined by Hofstadter in GEB (he certainly coined the verb _"to aritmoquine"_). But I'm not 100% sure. I heartily recommend everyone to read GEB (at least, everyone interested in Logic and/or Artificial Intelligence). IMHO, it is a masterpiece.

Answer (score 10):

You can also proof the existence of such programs without giving an example.
Let $(\Phi_i)$ be the list of all partial computable functions. Clearly there is a partial computable function $\varphi(k)$ which prints the input $k$ n times. So there is an Index $e$ with $\varphi(k) = \Phi_e(k)$. Using the smn-theorem we see that there is a computable function $f$ with $\Phi_{f(k)} = \Phi_e(k) = \varphi(k)$ for all $k$. Now we can apply the recursion theorem and get an $s$ with $\Phi_{f(s)} = \Phi_s$. So $\Phi_s$ is a program which outputs $s$ n times.

Answer (score 9):

Fun question! As a base I will use this Haskell quine I found on Wikipedia:

```
main=putStr(p++show(p))where p="main=putStr(p++show(p))where p="
```

You can make it print out two copies of itself by replacing the occurrences of p++show(p) with p++show(p)++p++show(p). If you see why, the pattern to achieve variable repetition should be clear.

I will be using the following function that calculates the nth iterate of f on x:

```
iterateN n f x = (iterate f x) !! n
```

I'll assume it's available as a library function. You can easily embed its definition directly in the quine, but that would clutter the presentation without good reason. Now the rest is simple:

```
main=putStr(iterateN 42(++(p++show(p)))[])
  where p="main=putStr(iterateN 42(++(p++show(p)))[])where p="
```

The line break was inserted to aid readability; remove it if you want exact self-replication.

Comment: Very nicely done!

Answer (score 3):

Here is another one, based on the printf-version on wikipedia:

```
main() { int i=5; char *s="main() { int i=5; char *s=%c%s%c; while (i--)
  printf(s,34,s,34); }"; while (i--) printf(s,34,s,34); }`
```

Though it is short, it is actually not so nice, as it lacks the inclusion for printf, as well as the counter has to be specified twice.
A slightly longer version cures both issues:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define k 5
main() { int i=k; char *s="#include <stdio.h> %c#define k %d%cmain() { int i=k;
  char *s=%c%s%c; while (i--) printf(s,10,k,10,34,s,34); }";
  while (i--) printf(s,10,k,10,34,s,34); }
```